# C#: Multiple Event Raises

Tags: c#, .net, events

My question is related to events:

I have Class with a `TaskAComplete` Event that is raised when `TaskA` is complete.

When a button is pressed I subscribe the `TaskACompleteEvent`

```
MyObject.TaskAComplete += new EventHandler(MethodToCall);
```

But in other Event I want to Unsubscribe from the `TaskAComplete` Event when the Event occurs the first time.

with:

```
MyObject.TaskAComplete -= MethodToCall;
```

And then when the Button is pressed the next time to Subscribe the `TaskAComplete` Event again.

Now when i start the Application and click on the Button the first time it raises the Event correctly.But when i click on the Button the second time the Event is raises two times in a row. (Third time click ->Event is raised three times in a row and so on..)

When i Subscribe the Event in the Contructor of the Form it only raises one time at every click.

Why the Event comes several times?

Answer (score 1):

When you subscribe to an event, you are subscribing by providing a *delegate* to a method. A delegate is effectively a strongly-typed, object-oriented approach to a C/C++ function pointer.

This delegate then goes into the list of calls for the event.

When you do `new EventHandler(MethodToCall)` you are explicitly creating that delegate. However, when you do `-= MethodToCall`, you are removing an "automatic" delegate. It is as if you wrote `-= new EventHandler(MethodToCall)`. Obviously, this new delegate is not the one in the invocation list.

To do what you want, on add, you need to save the new delegate in a variable, which you can later remove. For example:

```
var handler = new EventHandler(MethodToCall);
MyObject.TaskAComplete += handler;
// later on
MyObject.TaskAComplete -= handler;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but in not worked!! I get multple events again! What i did: Create a member variable "handler" as a EventHandler, then Assign a "MethodToCall" to it with new in the constructor, used MyObject.TaskComplete += handler to subscribe the Event at the Button_Click Method, then unsubscribe with MyObject.TaskComplete -= handler in an other Event Method, Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to subscribe to the event *once*. If you subscribe multiple times with the same handler, that handler will be invoked multiple times just like you are seeing.

Why do you want to unsubscribe from the `TaskAComplete` event in the first place? If your other code is correct, you will get it exactly once for each task.

Comment: I have something like a State Machine and i in different states different events are allowed or not. Thats the reason i need to block the Event. How it could be done?